# Unusual format to simple math method in Java

Tags: java, math, double

I am writing a simple converter Java Android application and I am having some trouble with the output I am receiving from one conversion. My input is 0.508; converting from meters to km. The value I would be hoping for is 0.000508. However, I get the value 5.08E-4. This confuses me. The calculation I am using is simple, shown below.

```
private double mToKm(double m)
{
    return m / 1000;
}
```

Thanks, for any help!

Comment: 5.08e-4 **is** 0.000508.  If you want to format things differently, you should explore `System.out.printf()`.

Comment: I thought they would be the same. Do you know how I would go about doing this in android? Thanks

Comment: You should write 1000D instead of 1000.

Comment: @vhunsicker m is already a double so it is unnecessary and won't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks assylias! Wanted to go sure. The real problem is the formatting as stated by Oli Charlesworth already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. `System.out.printf("%f",mToKm(0.508));`

Comment: I have attempted to append D to the end of 1000. However, this has made no change.

Comment: This is the printf example. Doesn't work either? The D is best practice only. ;-) For a better formatting have a look into java.util.Formatter.

Comment: I have the required result by formatting the output string.
String val = String.format("%f",value);

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As stated by many people. This is a formatting error. I have fixed this by formatting the double as a string before it is displayed to the user.

```
String val = String.format("%f", value);
```

Thanks for the help everyone!